# Regex for special character and string pattern in text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to determine whether textarea text contains some special variable with pattern:

```
##Contact.some_text_here##

txtareaval= 'Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.Address 3##" /]some[variable field="##Contact.Comments##" /][variable field="##Contact.ContactCompany##" /]Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.Email##" /]some[variable field="##Contact.Fax Number##" /]Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.First Name##" /]Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.Home Number##" /] Some text some text.';
```

I am using something like `\W##[C][o][n][t][a][c][t][.]` . Not working though.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WrfY/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this, hope it works for you:

```
var res = str.match(/"##Contact[.].+?"/g);
```

The pattern goes like this. First, use the `/ /` characters to surround your regular expression argument to the **match** function. Then, supply your regex option (in this case **`g`** for global, otherwise the regex engine just returns after the first match).

Next, for the pattern itself, I used the double-quotes as part of the look-up expression to surround what I'm looking for (as was part of your target string), and the `##` contact you had in your original regular expression. Add the complementary `##` pair if needed.

The `[.]` in class notation is to target the dot as is rather than have the dot interpreted as a wildcard (its special meaning in regular expressions). Alternatively you could have used `\.` (escaped dot).

And finally, the `.+?` means match any character at least once (up until the next double-quote in this case), and non-greedy (by means of the question mark sign). Without the non-greedy marker, the regex engine would be recognizing characters until the very last double-quote in your string, forcing you to have to break down your string yet again.

Try playing around with the variations in jsFiddle to learn it for yourself. Try removing the `?` sign, try removing the `g` option at the end, try replacing the `+` with a `*` and see what happens. For the `+` replaced by a `*`, add a string that contains only `Contact."` and see what happens.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/happyd/4WrfY/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
##Contact\.[A-Za-z0-9\ ]+##
```

The match would be two # characters followed by "Contact." string then one or more letter, number or space characters followed by two # characters again.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw3xZ/) link

Comment: `#` matches literally, you don't need to escape it.

Comment: was helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need this regex:

```
str.match(/\W##Contact\./);
```

Your regex is this:

```
str.match("\W##[C][o][n][t][a][c][t][.]")
```

Which won't work because `String#match` needs a regex which has to be between `/ and /` OR else a `RegExp` object.

Besides that you have unnecessary character classes all over like `[C]` and `[o]` etc that can be simplified as well.

Comment: technically speaking, his code doesn't contain a regex at all

Comment: was helpful.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test if it contains the pattern, you can use this regex: `/##Contact\..+?##/`

But I think you're looking to replace each one with some value. Perhaps something like this...

```
var pattern = /##Contact\.(.+?)##/g;

var txtareaval= 'Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.Address 3##" /]some[variable field="##Contact.Comments##" /][variable field="##Contact.ContactCompany##" /]Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.Email##" /]some[variable field="##Contact.Fax Number##" /]Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.First Name##" /]Some text some text [variable field="##Contact.Home Number##" /] Some text some text.';

var replacedValue = txtareaval.replace(pattern, function(match, capture){
    if (capture === "Address 3") {
        return "Some Address";
    } else if (capture === "Comments") {
        return "Some Comment";
    } else if (capture === "ContactCompany") {
        return "Some Company";
    } else if (capture === "Email") {
        return "somewhere@mail.com";
    }

    //... more conditions here...

    return "";
});
```

Fiddle here: [JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Utv84/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Utv84/1/)